# Cannot access HDD files through Linux Mint Live USB

Tags: linux-mint, usb, disk

I have valuable info on my Ubuntu partition, but it crashed, and I tried to get to it through Live USB with Mint 14, but it says it's read only. Can I make it writable too? So I can put it on  my flash drive?

Comment: Community, you just bumped a 2013 question... This is a really sad state of affairs, if you feel doing that is appropriate. Under Linux, most such "unanswered" questions are single-use throw-away distro, kernel or application bug related questions, so you bumping them is nothing but traffic inflation and click baiting. Should consider better AI rules for bumping.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your Linux Mint Live USB, did you include persistence to allow for changes (like transfering files or setting changes) to be made?

If not, I recommend using LiLi USB Creator or whatever you originally used to create a Linux Mint Live USB with persistence.  I believe you need a 2GB or higher sized USB drive/SD Card to create a Live USB with persistence which may be needed if you have a lot of data to rescue, but the limit is a 4GB space reservation for persistence unless you want to have a more challenging time on a workaround.

If you can't access any other drives on your Linux Mint 14 Live USB it is likely because of a bug in the OS saying that it can't mount anything.  I looked around on forums because I could not access any drives due to a mounting problem that I solved by typing the following lines into the terminal: press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in each line.

`sudo mkdir /media/$USER`

`sudo chown $USER.$USER /media/$USER`

Comment: It may also be that the Ubuntu partition is mounted readonly.  If that is the case, # mount -o rw,remount /wherever/ubuntu/is/mounted will take care of that :)

Answer (score 0):

Good day! Data recovery is better to go the other way. I use Parted Magic or Ultimate Boot CD. These boot disks provide access to the HDD. And also have a variety of special tools data recovery, such testdisk